# emulator and uploading video

Tags: android, video, upload

Does anyone help me about android emulator? I am trying to push a .mpg file into the sd card but I can not see the file when I run my application. Does emulator support .mpg files?

Secondly, I want to upload a video to asp.net server but I can not send the file and I get the out of memory error in my code. I am using multi part upload. On the other hand this code is able to upload a jpeg file to the server and it was successful.

Comment: Now after adding the connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) file.length()); I am getting 0 kb on the server side does anyone have any idea please?

Comment: paste the code that you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to upload a file to emulator instance

- create a new emulator using AVD. make sure that you have chosen 'SD Card support' for this. refer image below

[image: AVD with SD card support]

- Start the AVD and wait till the emulator loads fully
- Now in eclipse IDE, select `DDMS` perspective, by `Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS`
- Select `File Explorer` tab to get the directory tree of your device.
- Select `mnt -> sdcard` folder. This is your SD card
- Now use the 'Push file onto the device' button on top to push a file to the emulator instance.

[image]

- The file is in the SD card of your emulator